# Unable to display image retrieved using Hibernate on a JSP file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. I would like to save images in database and display them in the JSP page of the application. Currently I am able to save images in database, but unable to display them in the front end.
The image is not displayed, and when I click on view image, I get an Apache error :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /product/%5BB@a2e6ab9
```

I generally use to think, this will be binary image, and the image displayed will show full binary data when clicked on view, but thats not the case. Now I will paste controller, entity and JSP code I am using for display.

Controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{id}/image")
    public byte[] retrieveimage(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,@PathVariable("id")Integer id){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        ProductBasic productBasic1 = productBasicService.getProductById(id);
        BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        byte[] data =  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(productBasic1.getProductimage());
        return data;

    }

@RequestMapping(value="/product/show",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listProducts(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,Model model){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("product", new ProductBasic());
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",this.productBasicService.listProduct(user));
       BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        if(productBasic.getProductimage()==null){
            System.out.println("getProductImage is null"); // This is always returning null when I check
            return "product";
        }else {
            String image = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Encoder.encode(productBasic.getProductimage());
            model.addAttribute("saveimage", image);
            return "product";
        }
    }
```

JSP :

```
<h3>Product List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listProducts}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Product ID</th>
            <th width="80">Product image</th>
            <th width="120">Product name</th>
            <th width="120">Product description</th>
            <th width="120">Product condition</th>
            <th width="120">Product age</th>
            <th width="120">Product EAN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ISBN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ordernumber</th>
            <th width="120">Product owners id</th>

            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.productid}</td>
                <td>${product.productimage} </td>
                <td>${product.productname}</td>
                <td>${product.productdescription}</td>
                <td>${product.productcondition}</td>
                <td>${product.productage}</td>
                <td>${product.productean}</td>
                <td>${product.productisbn}</td>
                <td>${product.ordernumber}</td>
                <td>${product.user1id}</td>
                <img src="${product.productimage}" height="100" width="100"/>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Edit Product</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removeproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Delete Product</a></td>
            </tr>
            <%--<img src="${saveimage}" height="100" width="100">--%>
        </c:forEach>


    </table>
</c:if>
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductBasic {

@Column(name = "productimage")
    byte[] productimage;
}



public byte[] getProductimage() {
        return productimage;
    }

public void setProductimage(byte[] productimage) {
    this.productimage = productimage;
}
```

DAOImpl :

```
 @Override
    public List<byte[]> listImage(User user){
        int id = user.getId();
        if(session == null){
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        } else{
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductBasic as p where p.user1.id=:id order by p.ordernumber");
        query.setParameter("id",id);
        List<ProductBasic> productBasicList= query.list();
        List<byte[]> images=null;
        if(productBasicList.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        } else {
            for (ProductBasic productBasic : productBasicList) {
                images.add(productBasic.getProductimage());  // Here there is nullPointer Exception
            }
            return images;
        }
    }
}
```

@Shazin :

Saving images in Service like this :

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addProduct(User user, ProductBasic p){
        p.setProductimage(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(p.getProductimage()));
        this.productBasicDAO.addProduct(user, p);
    }
```

Getter in entity for productImage is :

```
 public byte[] getProductimage() {
        return productimage;
    }

    public void setProductimage(byte[] productimage) {

        this.productimage = productimage;
    }
```

When I click on view image in firefox, I get following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown return value type [[B]
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering why I am not using Bob or Clob for image persistence, I see only OID option when I add a column using PGAdmin3. I am using Postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: What should I give then? I am doing work on images for first time, and all references I find are not suitable. Can you please tell me.

Comment: where are getters and setters of Productbasic class?

Comment: @DeepakTiwari Getters and setters added in main post.

Answer (score 0):

HTML `img` tag doesn't work with binary byte data. It has a `src` attribute which accepts a URL which it uses retrieve the image binary byte data using a separate GET request.

What you can do is have a Controller method to return the binary byte data like

```
/product/{id}/image
```

which must return the binary byte data when provided with the {id}.

with this you can change your code like the following

#### Product List

Product ID
            Product image
            Product name
            Product description
            Product condition
            Product age
            Product EAN
            Product ISBN
            Product ordernumber
            Product owners id

```
        <th width="60">Edit</th>
        <th width="60">Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.productid}</td>
            <td>${product.productimage} </td>
            <td>${product.productname}</td>
            <td>${product.productdescription}</td>
            <td>${product.productcondition}</td>
            <td>${product.productage}</td>
            <td>${product.productean}</td>
            <td>${product.productisbn}</td>
            <td>${product.ordernumber}</td>
            <td>${product.user1id}</td>
            <!-- This Changed -->
            <img src="/product/${product.productid}/image" height="100" width="100"/>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/editproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Edit Product</a></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/removeproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Delete Product</a></td>
        </tr>
        <%--<img src="${saveimage}" height="100" width="100">--%>
    </c:forEach>


</table>
```

Comment: Hello Shazin, Thank you for your answer, as you can see I tried to encode the image using Base64Encoder, but  String image = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64Encoder.encode(productBasic.getProductimage()); throws me a nullPointerException as getProductImage always returns null.

Comment: I have added the method in controller as you said, please check the updated post. It still cannot display image.

Comment: Are you sure productBasic1.getProductimage() returns a byte array? and do you Base64 encode before saving the array?

Comment: Yes. Please go to end of post, I have updated post for u

Answer (score 0):

I think we should get the url of image from  ${product.productimage} rather than binary data.
So the property "productimage" of Product  can be string type. we can storage a url in DB such as "/xxx/xxx.Jpg"

Comment: I would like to store them in database and display them, I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: Well,I mean that we can save a url of the picture in database. we can get the url as string from DB. Then you can display the picture (using src).